# Determine how many days into the year a certain date is when the date is determined by a variable

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is check column AJ for each date that occurs during a year determined by variable "Año". For the dates that are I would like to see how far into the year they are (that is how many days after the first January each date occurs); this is the part that is giving me the error (indicated in my code).  What I need is a function to give how many days into the year a date occurs or a better way of writing that line of code.

```
For Each cl In Workbooks(WbkA).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AJ2:AJ1000")
    If (cl.Value - ("01/01/" & Año)) > 0 And (cl.Value - ("01/01/" & Año)) < 366 Then 'if it´s   in this year
        ValueA = ValueA + (cl.Value * ((cl.Offset(0, -13).Value - ("01/01/" & Año)) / 365)) ' this part is giving me the error
    End If
End If
```

Next cl

Comment: what is the error and what is in the cell 13 columns to the left?

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things too much. `DateDiff` can perform the calculations you want:

```
Dim iniDate As Date, curDate As Date
Dim ValueA As Integer, Año As Integer
Año = 2010
iniDate = Format(CDate("01/01/" & Año), "MM/dd/yyyy") 'You can change the Format
curDate = Format(CDate("01/05/" & Año), "MM/dd/yyyy")
ValueA = DateDiff("d", iniDate, curDate) 'RESULT -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as the number of days since 1/1/1900, so you can just subtract two dates to get the number of days.

```
Dim lAno As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim dValueA As Double

lAno = 2010

For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("AJ2:AJ100").Cells
    If Year(rCell.Value) = lAno Then 'if it's in the year
        '+= some value * the number of days
        dValueA = dValueA + (rCell.Offset(0, -13).Value * (rCell.Value - DateSerial(lAno, 1, 1)))
    End If
Next rCell
```